# How to use API to get Country,State,District

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to use API to get Country, State, District I am new to ajax so any one can help me thanks in advance

**Ajax**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    let api_url = 'http://www.postalpincode.in/api/pincode/';
    $('#pincode').on('focusout',function(){
        let pin = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:api_url+pin,
          // contentType:"application/json",
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(result){
            console.log(result);
          }
        });
    });
  })
```

pin:-334003

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to change your POST request to GET since it is a get request this gives error API Method Not Allowed when you use POST.
2. you can get your values like this 
   `console.log(result);` will show you complete response from API in your console and you can get your values like this

   console.log(result.PostOffice[0].Country);

Hope this helps

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.postalpincode.in/pincode/334003' from origin 'http://jobnear.in' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Comment: Can you share the updated request you are sending, its happening because you are calling API from different origin